# Fetch video meta information - GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have video contents uploaded in GCP buckets.

Is there a way by which I can get video meta data(height, width, duration) from any of gcp api / class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stat` command in `gsutil` tool.

**Example:**

```
gsutil stat gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME]
```

There are also other ways to obtain metadata.

 Further Reference: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata